# OpenAPI Generator - Java Client generating different model than Spring Server

Tags: java, spring, jackson, openapi-generator

I'm trying to create the server and a client from the same api spec (v3.0.2) by using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin (v6.2.1).

For the server i'm using

```
<generatorName>spring</generatorName>
<library>spring-boot</library>
```

and for the client

```
<generatorName>java</generatorName>
<library>webclient</library>
```

In the api spec I'm having an object with a list of items.
The items can be one of two types.

```
   Section:
      type: object
      properties:
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemInput'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemOutput'
```

For the two types I added a base class with a discriminator property set to 'type'

```
    SectionItemBase:
      required:
      - type
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
```

Finally the two types look like this

```
    SectionItemInput:
      type: object
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemBase'
      - type: object
        properties:
          input:
            type: string

    SectionItemOutput:
      type: object
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemBase'
      - type: object
        properties:
          output:
            type: string
```

After building the server, I get these models

Section.java

```
public class Section {
  @JsonProperty("items")
  @Valid
  private List<SectionItemsInner> items = null;
  ...
```

SectionItemsInner.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "type", // ignore manually set type, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the type to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemInput.class, name = "SectionItemInput"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemOutput.class, name = "SectionItemOutput")
})

public interface SectionItemsInner {
    public String getType();
}
```

SectionItemBase.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "type", // ignore manually set type, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the type to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemInput.class, name = "SectionItemInput"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemOutput.class, name = "SectionItemOutput")
})

public class SectionItemBase { ...
```

SectionItemInput.java

```
public class SectionItemInput extends SectionItemBase implements SectionItemsInner { ...
```

SectionItemOutput.java

```
public class SectionItemOutput extends SectionItemBase implements SectionItemsInner { ...
```

This seems fine.

But when I build the client I get

Section.java

```
public class Section {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_ITEMS = "items";
  private List<SectionItemsInner> items = null;
  ...
```

Up until here, it also seems fine. But starting with the SectionItemsInner it differs.

SectionItemsInner.java

```
@JsonTypeName("Section_items_inner")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "type", // ignore manually set type, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the type to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemInput.class, name = "SectionItemInput"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemOutput.class, name = "SectionItemOutput"),
})

public class SectionItemsInner { ...
```

The generator creates a class instead of an interface like with the server generator.
Also it has all the properties of the type whichever comes last in the spec for the Section schema.

SectionItemBase.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "type", // ignore manually set type, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the type to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemInput.class, name = "SectionItemInput"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemOutput.class, name = "SectionItemOutput"),
})

public class SectionItemBase { ...
```

SectionItemBase has just the base properties, but there is no relationship between the SectionItemsInner and the SectionItemBase.

SectionItemInput.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "type", // ignore manually set type, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the type to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)

public class SectionItemInput extends SectionItemBase { ...
```

SectionItemInput extends SectionItemBase but also has no relation to SectionItemsInner.

After creating the server I wrote a body for a sample request

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "SectionItemOutput",
      "name": "output",
      "output": "TestOutput"
    },
    {
      "type": "SectionItemInput",
      "name": "input",
      "output": "TestInput"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I post this to the server, it gets parsed correctly and I can do something with it.
But when I try to parse this on the client

```
InputStream json = ...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Section s = mapper.readValue(json, Section .class);
```

I get an error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'SectionItemOutput'
as a subtype of `org.openapitools.client.model.SectionItemsInner`:
Class `org.openapitools.client.model.SectionItemOutput` not subtype of
`org.openapitools.client.model.SectionItemsInner`
   at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 4, column: 16] (through reference chain:
      org.openapitools.client.model.Section["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

I'm very sorry for this long post, but it seems that I'm stucked.
I tried a few different other libraries (okhttp-gson, resttemplate, webclient) but none of them generates code which is compatible.

Thanks for any help or hint, bernd

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, the java client generator (and its libraries) doesn't [currently support polymorphism](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#schema-support-feature), but the `Spring` [generator does](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md).

| **Spring** | **Java** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Spring schema support structure] | [image] |

There are several options to work around this:

1. You can force the webclient to implement the interface generated by the Spring generator by using the `x-implements` vendor extension.  However, this would require you to use two copies of the same schema, one with and one without the vendor extension.
2. you can disable the model generation for your webclient and have it use all of the models generated by the spring generator.

Here's an example of your schema with the x-implements extension.  I took the liberty of cleaning it up a bit as well (I hate those inner classes).

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Section:
      type: object
      properties:
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/SectionItem"
    SectionItem:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemInput'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemOutput'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
    SectionItemBase:
      required:
        - type
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
    SectionItemInput:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemBase'
        - type: object
          title: SectionItemInputDetails
          properties:
            input:
              type: string
      x-implements:
        - 'generated.model.spring.SectionItem'
    SectionItemOutput:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SectionItemBase'
        - type: object
          title: SectionItemOutputDetails
          properties:
            output:
              type: string
      x-implements:
        - 'generated.model.spring.SectionItem'
```

Comment: thanks skidwiz,
i tried the x-implements way. this creates for example this class
`public class SectionItemInput extends SectionItemBase implements generated.model.spring.SectionItem`
so far so good, but the `SectionItem` is generated as a class, not an interface
`...
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemInput.class, name = "SectionItemInput"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SectionItemOutput.class, name = "SectionItemOutput"),
})
public class SectionItem { ...`
any idea why this happens and how to fix this?
thanks, bernd

Comment: The Java generator doesn't support polymorphism (You can see this with the X next to polymorphism in the screenshot I shared in my answer).  That means that, as of right now, it won't create the interface like you are wanting.  So, when you define the `x-implements` in your generator, you should implement the `SectionItem` generated from the spring generator.  The only other option would be to create your own generator.

Comment: why would the client have the interface generated by the spring generator?
server and client are two separate projects without any shared dependencies.

Comment: in proxy like settings, it's not unlikely that the same server might act as server and client of the same api.
Let's say you want to call an unsafe api server, perform some security filter & validation, maybe redact some data and forward it to your client. Maybe, you don't even want your client to change, maybe you don't want your client to be aware of this proxy logic. Maybe you want to keep things simple for yourself.

Use cases might include
backend-for-frontend pattern
strangler pattern ~> new server takes over requests partially
gateway pattern, filters and such